# How to correctly connect react components using useContext and useRef

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, use-effect

I would like to after button onclick event call method of component which uses external library (leafletjs). Here is basic example. My button just sets true or false value in Context.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { ToolContext } from "../../../context/ToolContext";

function IsochroneTool() {
  let {
    generateIso,
    setGenerateIso,
  } = useContext(ToolContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Button
        size={"small"}
        onClick={() => {
          setGenerateIso(true);
        }}
      >
        Generate
      </Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default IsochroneTool;
```

In my Map component there is useEffect hook which is vulnerable on changes of context and do some logic.

```
export default function Map(props) {
    let {
        generateIso, setGenerateIso,
    } = useContext(ToolContext)
    const mapRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
            mapRef.current = L.map(props.id, {
                editable: true,
                zoomControl: false,
                contextmenu: true,
                maxZoom: 20,
                minZoom: 6,
                doubleClickZoom: false,
                contextmenuWidth: 120,
            })
        }, []
    );



    useEffect(() => {
        if (generateIso) {
          // do my stuff add or remove objects and layers from mapRef.current 
          // or call some internal methods of leaflet 
          
        //   L.marker([0,0]).addTo(mapRef.current)

        }
        setGenerateIso(false)
    }, [generateIso])

    useGenerateIsoHook(generateIso, mapRef.current)

    return (
        <>
                <div
                    ref={mapRef}
                    id={props.id} style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    // top: 0,
                    // left: 0,
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "calc(100vh - 64px)",
                }}>
                </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

The code works fine, but how to write it simpler? Is it correct? The problem is in my context there are a lot of consts to do some checks because useEffect is fired. I would like to do write some custom hooks to use this functions in different map components

here is dummy example

```
export const useGenerateIsoHook =  (removeIsoTrigger, myref) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (generateIso) {
            // do my stuff add or remove objects and layers to mapRef.current 
          }
          setGenerateIso(false)
    }, [generateIso])

}
```

how to write them properly?

Comment: The code it working and this question is asking for more of a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I’m voting to close this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a "correct" way to write what you're describing, only the solution that best fits your needs. Therefore, my answer will be subjective, but it seems like you're interested in a custom hook which I can help you with.

To start, you can hook into it within the custom hook and then pass along the methods via a return statement. Second, there's no need for a useEffect here, what you really want is a callback when you need to generate the map. You can update context with the callback

I assume you have a parent "provider" component passing along context, so you a callback instead of a flag:

```js
const isoContext = createContext({
  onGenerateIso: undefined,
  setOnGenerateIso: undefined
});

const Provider = () => {
  const [onGenerateIso, setOnGenerateIso] = useState(() => null);
  const contextValue = {
    onGenerateIso,
    setOnGenerateIso
  };

  return (
    <isoContext .Provider value=contextValue>
    ...
    </isoContext .Provder>
  );
}
```

```js
export const useGenerateIsoHook = () => useContext(isoContext);
```

In Map component use the hook to set the callback

```js
  const { setOnGenerateIso } = useGenerateIsoHook();
  const generateIso = useCallback(() => {
    if (myMapRef.current) {
      // do stuff with map ref
    }
  }, [myMapRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOnGenerateIso(generateiso);
  }, [generateiso]);
```

In Tool component use the callback:

```js
const { onGenerateIso } = useGenerateIsoHook();

<Button
   size={"small"}
   disabled={typeof(onGenerateIso) !== 'function'}
   onClick={() => onGenerateIso()}
>
   Generate
</Button>
```